# Sendgrid API Usage

Tags: php

I want to know email delivery status via sendgrid API in php script.
I am not getting the exact function name which will return open, click, deliver status for a particular email id.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
$response = $sg->client->FUNCTION_NAME->get();
var_dump( $response->body() );
```

Comment: something like that https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SendGrid's Webhooks to receive information on individual emails.
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/index.html

Another option is to use the Stats endpoints in SendGrid's WebAPI v3 to get those types of statistics about emails. Documentation is available at 
https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Stats/index.html

For example:

```
<?php
// If you are using Composer
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$apiKey = getenv('SENDGRID_API_KEY');
$sg = new \SendGrid($apiKey);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Retrieve global email statistics #
// GET /stats #
$query_params = json_decode('{"aggregated_by": "day", "limit": 1, "start_date": "2016-01-01", "end_date": "2016-04-01", "offset": 1}');
$response = $sg->client->stats()->get(null, $query_params);
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->body();
print_r($response->headers());
```

Reference: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Comment: i want to know the status for a particular email id.

Comment: First, search the email using above code and get particular the email status.

Comment: I think you can search by email id also. See here https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Stats/advanced.html
Just replace the arguments in the `$query_params`

Comment: Is there any way that i just pass an email id as parameter and i'll get all its stats?
I am unable to find the API name or function.

Answer (score 0):

As per the  sendgrid documentation https://sendgrid.com/docs/Glossary/opens.html
It might be possible that you don't get accurate  numbers.

```
$response = $sg->client->tracking_settings()->open()->get();
echo $response->statusCode();
echo $response->body();
print_r($response->headers());
```

// Reference url : https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php/blob/master/examples/trackingsettings/trackingsettings.php

Comment: this will return open setting only